# Update database files in Winrt (Metro) applications

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an app which uses a xml file as database. This file is created in the project as you see:
[image]

I want to keep this file updated by the following procedure in the splash screen:

**procedure**

1. get the last modified dates of the local xml file and the remote xml
   file(http://www.somewhereontheinternet.com/data.xml)
2. compare these two dates
3. if the remote one has the most recent modified date then download
   it and replace the local one with it

The application will be deployed to the clients via Windows Store.

If you think about the restrictions, limitations, policies and possibilities, can I keep the deployed app's database files updated as described above? If not how can I keep my app's data updated then?

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1) It will be more clean to do this by associating a `version` to the database. local `version` can be stored in the [application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) as local state or setting. remote `version` can be queried using a web api.

2) do you want user to know about this? can user force update of the database? accordingly, knobs may need to be exposed in the UI.

3) if the size of the file is significant, may have to do the download using [background transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452975.aspx).

steps will look something like this:

1. check remote version when the app is launched (async).
2. if the versions differ, schedule background transfer or download while the app is running depending on the size of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've noted them. But I'm also worried about the _restrictions, limitations and possibilities_. Would Windows Store allow this kind of approach in the app, would the app can edit the files which are located in his installation directory, would be a missing library limitation, etc..?

Comment: Updating the application data (not installation) which seem to the case here - should be fine and pass store guidelines.